# SQLite executing .import cmd from Java

Tags: java, database, shell, sqlite

I want to use the sqlite3 shell command .import to load a tab separated file into my database.

Executing the command from shell is no problem!

Writing a shell script including the command and running it from Java is no problem!

```
#! /bin/bash
# Script for loading a specific file ($1) into a SQLite DBS table ($2)
{
    sqlite3 database.db -cmd ".mode tab" -cmd ".import $1 $2" -cmd ".quit" &
} 2> /dev/null
exit 0
```

**But how do I execute the command directly from Java?**
Here is what I've tried: But somehow nothing is loaded into the database

```
String[] cmd={"sqlite3","database.db -cmd \".mode tab\" -cmd \".import\" "+file.getPath()+" "+table+" -cmd \".quit\""};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try executing the commands grouped by double-quotes.

```
sqlite3 database.db ".mode tab" ".import $1 $2"
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I was trying `sqlite3 db ".mode csv test;.import $f test;"` and it wasn't working (do you know why?). Then I used `sqlite3 db ".mode csv test" ".import $f test"` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I do not find the "-cmd" option from the SQLite3 shell docs: http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html. I tried the shell script you provided:

```
sqlite3 database.db -cmd ".mode tab" -cmd ".import data.in Test" -cmd ".quit"
```

The error gets reported:

```
./sqlite3: Error: too many options: ".mode tab"
Use -help for a list of options.
```

To execute multiple commands on a SQLite shell, I would write all the commands in one file and use the ".read" command. For example, write the commands in **cmd.list**

```
.mode tabs
.import data.in Test
.quit
```

Then run the SQLite shell command:

```
sqlite3 database.db ".read cmd.list"
```

Java code:

```
String[] cmd = {"sqlite3", "database.db", ".read cmd.list"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this without using Runtime.exe(), i.e. strictly Java (Android)?